# Probleme OLE DB provider

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2008

I have a problem when I try to import data from Excel to a table in SQL Server I have a problem  I am totally blocked

I'm on Windows 7 64 bit, SQL Server 2008 Express. I import a file format  (.xls)

Here's the code:

```
SELECT Table_1.Champ1 , Table_1.Champ2
FROM Table_1
INNER JOIN OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Users\AA\Desktop\Classeur1.xls;',
'SELECT [Champ1], [Champ2] FROM [Feuil1$]') T
ON Table_1.Champ1 = T.[Champ1]
```

and this is the error :

> Msg 7308, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' can not be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in STA mode.

And I forget I also do this :

and I changed my query of course to this

```
SELECT Table_1.Champ1 , Table_1.Champ2
FROM Table_1
INNER JOIN OPENROWSET('MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Users\AA\Desktop\Classeur1.xls;',
'SELECT [Champ1], [Champ2] FROM [Feuil1$]') T
ON Table_1.Champ1 = T.[Champ1]
```

and this is the error:

> Msg 15281, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset / OpenDataSource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration of the server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', see "Surface Area Configuration exposure" in Books Online for SQL Server.

After I edited my code using this code I found it here  : 
[Get Excel sheet into temp table using a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090555/get-excel-sheet-into-temp-table-using-a-script?rq=1)

in stackoverflow

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;

RECONFIGURE;
GO

sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
GO

RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

and after I execute my query

```
SELECT Table_1.Champ1 , Table_1.Champ2
FROM Table_1
INNER JOIN OPENROWSET('MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Users\AA\Desktop\Classeur1.xls;',
'SELECT [Champ1], [Champ2] FROM [Feuil1$]') T
ON Table_1.Champ1 = T.[Champ1]
```

The error change to this  :

> Msg 7302, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Can not create an instance of OLE DB provider "MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)"

Help please

Comment: I searched and I found it necessary to download this http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 but nothing work the same probleme

Comment: Refer to this article to know how to use Microsoft data providers on 64 bit machine. http://blog.wharton.com.au/2011/10/19/ssis-consuming-microsoft-access-or-microsoft-excel-data-sources-in-64-bit-environments/

Comment: I have edited my message on high i forget to do that in first time

Comment: I believe that even if you get the STA/Ad-Hoc Distributed Queries settings configured "correctly" JET doesn't support distributed transactions at any level so you should consider removing your `SELECT` query from any ambient transaction

Comment: My objectif is join my table in sql server with table in my sheet of excel with any probleme so i can't remove Select querry :D

Comment: I am refered to this site http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1540/insert-update-or-delete-data-in-sql-server-from-excel/

Comment: This is an environment problem, and may not be soluble using Win7 client and SQL Server Express. Consider importing your table and performing the join as a separate step. Or try: http://dhinakaran-msbi.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/msg-15281-level-16-state-1-line-2-sql.html

Comment: I have eddited my message right now and OMG the same thing what i have done before seeing your message :D

Comment: and i have put my new error

Comment: I have install already install this  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Its solved yeaah !! my probleme was in office its was version of 32 bit and not 64 :D :D

Answer (score -2):

Right Click Your OLEDB Providor and Go to Properties and Check the Allow Inprocess