# How to use CSV data in an SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, csv

I have a some data in an excel sheet in the form of a table. I want to run an sql query on that data. I am okay to use the data raw from the csv.

Is it possible to create a temporary view or table using that data within the query itself. I don't want to create a separate table for this excel data.

Comment: what are you taking action for this csv

Comment: I assumed you are using SQL Server, however please provide which RDBMS you are using

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server 2008 and above you can use [OPENROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx)

In simplest form it will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'data.csv', SINGLE_CLOB) AS DATA;
```

Just remember to specify full file path.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of answers for this already... Have you searched?

You want to do something like this;

```
Select * 
into [temp_table$]
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\spreadsheet.xls;HDR=YES;IMEX=1',
'SELECT * FROM [SHEET1$]')
```

Like in this question: [Get Excel sheet into temp table using a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090555/get-excel-sheet-into-temp-table-using-a-script)